# How can I limit my Array to only a size of however many values are entered, when the maximum number possible to enter is 1000?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void displayListValues(int Array[], int Max)

   {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Max; i++)
        {
            cout << counter << " = " << Array[i] << endl;
            counter++;
        }
    }

void main()
   {
        const int Max = 1000;
        int Array[Max];  // this is where I couldn't figure out what to change so the array isn't so huge
        int counter = 0;
        cout << "Enter Numbers. If finished, enter a negative number to continue" << endl;
        do
        {
            cin >> Array[counter];
            if (Array[counter] < 0)
                break;

        } while (counter < Max);
        displayListValues(Array, Max);
    }
```

details details details, any assistance would be fantastic!!! Thanks guys!!!! :D :D :D
I don't know what else to include in here because it keeps saying my post is mostly code. I apologize for this nonsensical gibberish at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Where is the question?! what is the issue?!!

Comment: It's in the title : How can I limit my Array to only a size of however many values are entered, when the maximum number possible to enter is 1000?

Comment: @Nico Which is very unclear; Your grammar is bad; try to rephrase it differently; just to make it clear, however is adverb not adjective or how you meant to use it.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` instead of an array?

Comment: Your efforts and concern over less than 10,000 bytes (1000 ints)
appears premature.  This is a trivially small array for modern
machines.  Desktop computers typically have a much much larger default stack.  Ubuntu 12.04 reports that the default stack size for
threads is 8 M bytes (3 orders of magnitude bigger).  If your machine stacks are set smallish (perhaps you have a _lot_
of threads), then you might consider allocating the array on the
heap.  My desktop has 4 G of ram, probably 3 G available
(6 orders of magnitude bigger).

Comment: The exact words on the assignment for the class are as follows, just to let anyone know.
Write a C++ program that will:
 Allow the user to enter a list of decimal numbers until a negative number is 
entered.
 Allow at most 1000 numbers to be entered.
 Save all of the numbers entered into an array. (The negative number should not be 
included in the list.)
this was only partially what the assignment asked for but it was worded to suggest that the array could be limited based on user input, without asking for how many values could be entered.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you can't.  C/C++ arrays are a fixed size once defined.

The long answer is you need to use something other than an array.  You should use a `std::vector`, this behaves similar to an array but can be resized.

Comment: I agree about using std::vector, but be aware that it will "auto expand" as you push_back more and more values.  On Ubuntu, the simple std::vectors I've used start auto expanding with the 16th push_back, (and then again at 32, and 64, and 128, etc, each time doubling the vector size) but you will have to evaluate the growth pattern on your vector implementation.  Note that C++11 vectors have shrink-to-fit.  But of course, that suggests it has already expanded bigger than needed to hold the values, and therefor bigger than you wanted it to.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I would use what you described, but it is part of a class assignment and the instructions were written in such a way that suggested they were resizable in some respect. It's good to know that it isn't necessary possible with arrays, because I was thinking about how to do it for quite a while with no answer.